# Get all atributes of an XML to an 2d or 3d string array in C#

Tags: c#, xml

For my project I'm trying to translate or decrypt a XML API answer to an usable array of all the information.

Here is an example of the XML I'm receiving:

```
<users>
<User LoginName="test1" Owner="" Alias="" UserType="PAID" ClientType="OBM" Quota="10737418240" Timezone="GMT+08:00 (CST)" Language="en" DataFile="1" DataSize="1536" RetainFile="0" RetainSize="0" EnableMSSQL="Y" EnableMSExchange="Y" EnableOracle="Y" EnableLotusNotes="Y" EnableLotusDomino="Y" EnableMySQL="Y" EnableInFileDelta="Y" EnableShadowCopy="Y" EnableExchangeMailbox="N" ExchangeMailboxQuota="0" EnableNASClient="Y" EnableDeltaMerge="Y" EnableMsVm="N" MsVmQuota="0" EnableVMware="N" VMwareQuota="0" Bandwidth="0" Notes="" Status="ENABLE" RegistrationDate="1302687743242" SuspendPaidUser="N" SuspendPaidUserDate="20140503" LastBackupDate="1302699594652" EnableCDP="Y" EnableShadowProtectBareMetal="Y"EnableWinServer2008BareMetal="Y"
Hostname="123.abc.com" FileSizeLimit="52428800" ExcludeNetworkShare="Y"
><Contact Name=""Email="www@qqq.com"/>
</user>
```

I've succeeded to get one Attribute at once by using this code below:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Get attribute from XML file USE ONLY AS DEMO
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inputXML">XML string</param>
        /// <param name="requestVar">The requested variable in the XML response</param>
        /// <param name="parameter">Where the requested variable is located</param>
        /// <returns>string of all requested variables</returns>
        public static String GetAttribute(string inputXML, string requestVar, string parameter)
        {
            string vars = "";
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(inputXML);

            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.GetElementsByTagName(parameter);
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                vars = vars + xn.Attributes[requestVar].Value;
            }
            return vars;
        }
```

This function needs the node names where it can be found. For this project are many API calls necessary and would like a function which puts all the attributes in a string array. So far I tried to translate this part:

```
vars = vars + xn.Attributes[requestVar].Value;
```

to this:

```
foreach (XmlAttribute xa in xn)
{
    vars[i, j, k] = xa.Value;
    k++;
}
```

and I Also tried:

```
for (k = 0; k < xn.Attributes.Count; k++ )
{
    vars[i, j, k] = xn.Attributes[k].Value;
}
```

But both codes won't work. How do I get a simpel for loop or foreach, which gets all the attributes in the array? And can this also be done with:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.GetElementsByTagName(parameter);
```

The i, j and k vars are used in the multiple loops: i is used for XmlNodeList, the j is used for the XmlNode and the k is used for the XmlAttribute.

In this array I would like to get all the info of the XML file in the same order, only the parts between the '""' is needed.

```
vars[0][0][0]= would stand for: <Users><User LoginName= (vars[<Users>][<User][LoginName]=
```

This is the function as far as I'm now:

```
public static String[,,] GetVars(string inputXML)
        {
            string[,,] vars = new string[100,50,50];
            int i, j, k;
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(inputXML);

            i = j = k = 0;
            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("Users");
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                {
                    foreach (XmlAttribute xa in xn)
                    {
                        vars[i, j, k] = xa.Value;
                        k++;
                    }
                    k = 0;
                    j++;
                }
                j = 0;
            return vars;
```

Comment: Are you able to use LINQ to XML? That makes almost everything significantly simpler... (But it's really unclear what `i`, `j` and `k` are here...)

Comment: could you update the question to clearly define what you want the output to be?

Given your sample input XML, provide the string or array you are looking to get back from the function.

Comment: I've edited the question and I hope it's clear now. @JonSkeet I'm not sure if that's possible, I'm trying to create a function which won't need any TagNames or XML tag parameters.

Comment: My points is that if you can use `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`, life is simpler. I would also point out that using a cubic array for this is really odd - are you *sure* that's the representation you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JonSkeet, it is indeed a lot easier to use Xdocument. After a short while I've succeeded and created this code:

```
public static String[,] XGetVars(string inputXML)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(inputXML);
            int i = 0, j = 0, elementscounter = doc.Root.Elements().Count(), attributescounter = doc.Root.Elements().Attributes().Count();
            string[,] vars = new string[elementscounter,(attributescounter/elementscounter)];

            foreach (XElement element in doc.Root.Elements())
            {
                foreach (XAttribute attribute in element.Attributes())
                {
                    vars[i,j] = attribute.ToString();
                    j++;
                }
                j = 0;
                i++;
            }
            return vars;
        }
```

This method will create a 2D string array of the XML above. I will continue to get the node attributes as well.

EDIT:
As promised here's the new function which I'm using now:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Create 3D array of the XML response
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputXML">string XML file</param>
    /// <returns>3D string array of the XML file</returns>
    public static String[,,] GetVars(string inputXML)
    {
        try
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(inputXML);
            if (doc.Root.Elements().Attributes().Count() < 1 || ErrorMessage(doc)) return new string[1, 1, 1];//temp fix for empty xml files
            int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, elementscounter = doc.Root.Elements().Count(), attributescounter = doc.Root.Elements().Attributes().Count();
            string[,,] vars = new string[elementscounter, ((attributescounter / elementscounter) + getMaxNodes(doc)), getMaxNodesAttributes(doc)];

            foreach (XElement element in doc.Root.Elements())
            {
                foreach (XAttribute attribute in element.Attributes())
                {
                    vars[i, j, 0] = TrimVar(attribute.ToString());
                    j++;
                }
                foreach (XElement node in element.Nodes())
                {
                    foreach (XAttribute eAttribute in node.Attributes())
                    {
                        vars[i, j, k] = TrimVar(eAttribute.ToString());
                        k++;
                    }
                    k = 0;
                    j++;
                }
                j = 0;
                i++;
            }
            return vars;
        }
        catch (System.Xml.XmlException)
        {
            string[,,] vars = new string[1, 1, 1];
            vars[0, 0, 0] = "No XML found!";
            return vars;
        }
    }
        /// <summary>
        /// get the max nodes available by a Node
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="XML">XML string</param>
        /// <returns>Max nodes available</returns>
        private static Int32 getMaxNodes(XDocument XML)
        {
            int max = 1;
            foreach (XElement element in XML.Root.Elements())
            {
                if(element.Nodes().Count() > max) max = element.Nodes().Count();
            }
            return max;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// get the max attributes available by a Node
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="XML">XML string</param>
        /// <returns>Max attributes available</returns>
        private static Int32 getMaxNodesAttributes(XDocument XML)
        {
            int max = 1;
            foreach (XElement element in XML.Root.Elements())
            {
                foreach (XElement node in element.Nodes())
                {
                    if (node.Attributes().Count() > max) max = node.Attributes().Count();
                }
            }
            return max;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Trim the input string to only the value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">XML readout var</param>
        /// <returns>value of the XML readout var</returns>
        private static String TrimVar(string input)
        {
            return input.Remove(0, (input.IndexOf('"'))+1).TrimEnd('"');
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [System.Xml.Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization(v=vs.110).aspx) to accomplish this.

First I would create an object (containing class) that would encompass all of the elements and attributes that the XML would include.

Then assign the appropriate [Attributes That Control XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e(v=vs.110).aspx) to each property of the containing class object.

Then use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) to serialize the XML into a useable object.

I have provided an example below that would get you on the right track:

**Containing Class Object**

```
namespace XMLSerializationDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A container that contains properties relevant to a RUBI Object
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class RUBIObject
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Use a collection of some sort in order to encase the objects.**

```
namespace XMLSerializationDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Object that contains a collection of RUBIObjects which can be serialized into XML
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class RUBIObjectCollection
    {
        //Base Constructor which instantiates a collection of RUBIObjects
        public RUBIObjectCollection()
        {
            this.Objects = new List<RUBIObject>();
        }

        public List<RUBIObject> Objects { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

**Then create the methods for serializing the xml to and from a collection of objects:**

```
namespace XMLSerializationDemo
{
    public static class RUBIObjectSerialization
    {
        public static string SerializeToXML(this RUBIObjectCollection source)
        {
            //Create a string writer in order to output to console as opposed to file
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                //Settings to configure the way the XML will be output to the console. Really, only Indent = true; is needed.
                var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine;
                settings.IndentChars = "  ";
                settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace;
                settings.Indent = true;

                //Create writer that writes the xml to the string writer object
                using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
                {
                    //Create serializer that can serialize a collection of RUBIObjects
                    XmlSerializer serializer =
                        new XmlSerializer(typeof(RUBIObjectCollection));

                    //Serialize this instance of a RUBICollection object, into XML and write to the string writer output
                    serializer.Serialize(xw, source);

                    //Flush the xmlwriter stream as it isn't needed any longer
                    xw.Flush();
                }

                //Return the XML as a formatted string
                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }

        public static RUBIObjectCollection DeserializeToCollection(this string source)
        {
            RUBIObjectCollection collection = null;
            XmlSerializer serializer = null;

            //Read the XML string into a stream.
            using (var sr = new StringReader(source))
            {
                //Instantiate an XML Serializer to expect a collection of RUBI Objects
                serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RUBIObjectCollection));

                //Deserialize the XML stream to a collection
                collection = (RUBIObjectCollection)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
            }

            return collection;
        }
    }
}
```

**And this would be how it's all used from start to finish:**

```
public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create test data and add it to a collection
            var collection = DummyData();

            //Serialize the collection to XML and write to console.
            Console.WriteLine(collection.SerializeToXML());

            //Prevents console window from closing
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates dummy data for testing purposes
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A collection of RUBIObjects</returns>
        private static RUBIObjectCollection DummyData()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            var collection = new RUBIObjectCollection();

            //Build a collection of RUBIObjects and instantiate them with semi-random data.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                int month = random.Next(1, 12);     //Random month as an integer
                int year = random.Next(2010, 2015); //Random year as an integer

                //Create object and add to collection.
                collection.Objects.Add(new RUBIObject()
                    {
                        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        Name = string.Format("Object{0}", i),
                        Description = "Description",
                        CreatedOn = new DateTime(year, month, 1)
                    });
            }

            return collection;
        }
    }
```

**Bonus : And you can even toss in some Unit Testing to add some shine!**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using XMLSerializationDemo;

namespace UnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void DummyData_TestDataCreated()
        { 
            //Arrange
            PrivateType pt = new PrivateType(typeof(Program));

            //Act
            RUBIObjectCollection collection = (RUBIObjectCollection)pt.InvokeStatic("DummyData", null);
            int actualResult = collection.Objects.Count;
            int expectedResult = 10;

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(actualResult, expectedResult);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void SerializeToXML_GeneratesXMLString()
        {
            //Arrange
            bool actualResult = false;
            bool expectedResult = true;
            PrivateType pt = new PrivateType(typeof(Program));
            RUBIObjectCollection collection = (RUBIObjectCollection)pt.InvokeStatic("DummyData", null);

            //Act
            string serializedXml = collection.SerializeToXML();

            try
            {      
                System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(serializedXml);

                actualResult = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                actualResult = false;
            }

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(actualResult, expectedResult);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void DeserializeToCollection_DeserializedToRUBICollection()
        { 
            //Arrange 
            bool actualResult = false;
            bool expectedResult = true;
            XMLSerializationDemo.RUBIObjectCollection deserializedCollection = null;
            PrivateType pt = new PrivateType(typeof(XMLSerializationDemo.Program));
            XMLSerializationDemo.RUBIObjectCollection collection = (XMLSerializationDemo.RUBIObjectCollection)pt.InvokeStatic("DummyData", null);
            string serializedXml = collection.SerializeToXML();

            //Act
            try
            {
                deserializedCollection = serializedXml.DeserializeToCollection();
                if (deserializedCollection.Objects.Count > 0)
                    actualResult = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                actualResult = false;
            }

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(actualResult, expectedResult);
        }
    }
}
```

**Example XML Generated by the SerializeToXML custom extension method:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<RUBIObjectCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Objects>
    <RUBIObject ID="dac59571-e7eb-401b-b047-b72bd73628a9" Name="Object0" Description="Description" CreatedOn="2010-07-01T00:00:00" />
    <RUBIObject ID="42d4741b-ba3c-4db6-ac96-24abf819045d" Name="Object1" Description="Description" CreatedOn="2011-04-01T00:00:00" />
    <RUBIObject ID="bc3a2f2f-623a-4e18-be8a-2bf2f3cee841" Name="Object2" Description="Description" CreatedOn="2013-02-01T00:00:00" />
    <RUBIObject ID="51965f3b-c216-42c3-9893-ebe829d0b1d1" Name="Object3" Description="Description" CreatedOn="2014-07-01T00:00:00" />
    <RUBIObject ID="58492a02-291f-497d-87d8-152b7489a0b3" Name="Object4" Description="Description" CreatedOn="2014-06-01T00:00:00" />
    <RUBIObject ID="8b929041-4e6d-42f4-af16-aaa4c3c1d588" Name="Object5" Description="Description" CreatedOn="2011-05-01T00:00:00" />
    <RUBIObject ID="1f17d752-95ad-4d89-a2fe-fec6f5eeb713" Name="Object6" Description="Description" CreatedOn="2010-03-01T00:00:00" />
    <RUBIObject ID="73716b37-7c10-4aa5-9542-8a28d02d1a0b" Name="Object7" Description="Description" CreatedOn="2011-07-01T00:00:00" />
    <RUBIObject ID="a5a8ebe2-487f-462b-938d-49d4d07773bf" Name="Object8" Description="Description" CreatedOn="2014-08-01T00:00:00" />
    <RUBIObject ID="2d84bf1b-c012-495d-a0da-8adf45658ea6" Name="Object9" Description="Description" CreatedOn="2014-03-01T00:00:00" />
    <RUBIObject ID="492d4fe4-ae64-4e91-a38e-9c0353f73ffc" Name="Object10" Description="Description" CreatedOn="2012-06-01T00:00:00" />
  </Objects>
</RUBIObjectCollection>
```

Once you have a collection of useable objects, you can do what you like with it, such as iterate through each object and populate the said 2d/3d arrays that you had originally requested a solution for.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but it wasn't exactly what I was looking for. I've posted the Method which I created below.